Is there a way to change the value of a cell in a pandas dataframe column based on two conditionals?
I want to change the value of a string in a dataframe column based on two conditionals. Specifically, I want to check if the value of a string in one column matches an input, then if true, check for a substring value a few columns over.
For instance:
ID   Type    Name   Category
0    Blue   Large     d
1    Blue   Small     e
2    Red    Medium    f
3    Red    Large     g

If type is "Blue", then check "Name" for the substring "Larg" and, if found, change Category to "a".
I have functioning code that will do the second half (a one condition check, using example above):
def function(x):
 if 'Larg' in x:
    return 'a'
 else:
    return 'default'
df['Category'] = df['Name'].apply(function)


I've tried making a new df, filtering on blue, then running the one-condition code on the new df before finally merging back with the original, as such:
new_df = df[df['Type'] == 'Blue']
new_df['Category'] = new_df['Name'].apply(function)
merged_df = df.merge(new_df, on=['ID', 'Name'], how='left')


However this spits out x and y columns for the Category column that I'm unsure how to reconcile.
Maybe I can concatenate instead, then remove duplicates? Or maybe I can work an 'if' layer into the original function call? Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

E.g., try df.loc[df['Type'].eq('Blue') & df['Name'].str.contains('Larg'), 'Category'] = 'a'.

That nailed it, I was making it way too complicated. Thanks for the answer and the resource!
